# Issue with connecting zookeeper from spring boot with @EnableDiscoveryClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper

If I use the spring boot application as below, I am getting the warning message “More than one implementation of `@EnableDiscoveryClient` ********”.

Service instance is getting registered when I run this tomcat but same instance is not registering in JBOSS EAP 6.1

Warning  message in tomcat and JBOSS respectively
Tomcat:

Tomcat:

```
More than one implementation of @EnableDiscoveryClient (now relying on @Conditionals to pick one): 
[org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperDiscoveryClientConfiguration, 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration]
```

JBOSS EAP:

```
More than one implementation of @EnableDiscoveryClient (now relying on @Conditionals to pick one): 
[org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration, 
org.springframework.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.ZookeeperDiscoveryClientConfiguration]
```

We can notice the order of discovery clients are different in two servers, no sure because of this it’s registering in tomcar and not with JBOSS as I want to use ZookeeperDiscoveryClientConfiguration.

If I remove `@EnableDiscoveryClient` on spring boot, instance is connecting zookeeper but not registering.

But I want to run this in JBOSS EAP so is there anyway to disable loading EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration and use only ZookeeperDiscoveryClientConfiguration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
              SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
       }
}
```

Bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    zookeeper:
      connect-string: localhost:2181
      loadBalancerType: ROUND_ROBIN
```

Comment: Why did you need eureka in the classpath if you aren't using it?

Comment: I am adding eureka in the class path but it is getting added along with spring cloud libraries. No idea how to disable loading of eureka libraries

Comment: Stop adding it to your classpath?

Comment: @Dave, I have added the following modules in my pom.xml which might be loading eureka libraries also.  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery</artifactId>
  </dependency> not sure whether this is doing the trick

Comment: AFAIK none of those depends on eureka. You can find out where it comes from using "mvn dependency:tree".